# Why does assembly appear to be referenced but isn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a ASP.Net MVC project.
I was having trouble accessing the System.Configuration.Configuration class. 
It said it did not exist although I could reference System.Configuration.

The problem was the fact I hadnt added a reference to the System.Configuration assembly to the project.

Can anyone tell me why intellisense still found the System.Configuration class. Is it part of another default assembly?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed? It can (and will) add references in most of the cases.

Comment: No I don't, my office VS has ReSharper but this is just a home project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Configuration is a namespace, not a class.

Some classes of the System.Configuration namespace is defined in the System.dll assembly as well as the System.Configuration.dll.

e.g ConfigurationManager is part of System.Configuration.dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

while UriSection is part of System.dll